# Clone function speed: if/else vs short circuit evaluation

Tags: c++, performance, short-circuiting

I'm tweaking an algorithm that analyzes large amounts of data to make it run a little faster. It makes heavy use of `clone` functions like the following:

```
const Object* clone() const {
    if (this != INVALID_OBJECT) {
        return new DerivedObject(*this);
    } else {
        return this;
    }
}
```

The algorithm uses a pointer to a single invalid object to dramatically reduce memory requirements, and passing it through a copy constructor would defeat the purpose.

My question is whether using short circuit evaluation would increase the performance of the `clone` functions by reducing execution time:

```
const Object* clone() const {
    const Object* clonedObject = INVALID_OBJECT;
    (void)((this != INVALID_OBJECT)&&(clonedObject = new DerivedObject(*this));
    return clonedObject;
}
```

Is there any way to reduce the execution time of the `clone` functions? The copy constructors generally follow the pattern

```
DerivedObject(const DerivedObject& derivedObj) : Object(derivedObj.getField1()),
    field2(derivedObj.getField2()) {}
```

Comment: Other than making your code harder to read and maintain, those two functions will probably do nothing different and generate the same object code.

Comment: Have you profiled your code ?

Comment: Ask yourself, is clone necessary? Can I use ref-counting instead?

Comment: @Jarod42 Not yet, I've only just started optimizing and the clone functions are just about the only ones that have any branches

Comment: So, profile your code and you will see where you have to optimize. I'm pretty sure it is not your clone method the bottleneck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your optimization, complex as it may seem, is actually trivial, in the sense that it likely emits the same code than the previous one.

Think in low level operations, not syntax: one condition, one branch. It is difficult to do less.

**UPDATE**: I've noticed that I didn't really answer your question: Can it be done faster? Well, yes! You can write a subclass just for the uninitialized value.

```
class InvalidObject : public Object
{
public:
    const Object* clone() const {
        return this;
    }
};
```

And make the global `INVALID_OBJECT` an instance of this class:

```
Object *INVALID_OBJECT = new InvalidObject();
```

Now you don't need the condition in any of the `clone()` overrides:

```
class DerivedObject : public Object
{
public:
    const Object* clone() const {
        return new DerivedObject(*this);
    }
};
```

Naturally, depending on the structure of your hierarchy and the definition of your `INVALID_OBJECT` instance, you may need to write a `Invalid*` subclass for each `DerivedObject` type.

Comment: Possibly. I've read that short-circuit evaluation can be faster, but in this case I could see how it might produce _more_ low level operations due to the extra assignment

Comment: @mablem: even the extra assignments will be optimized away by the compiler. I see both pieces of code as virtually identical.

Comment: An other possible opportunity of optimization is to use the `final` keyword (`class InvalidObject final : public Object` and `const Object* DerivatedObject::clone() const final`.